# nginx dynamic ssl for SaaS application

Tags: nginx, docker, devops

my SaaS application create subdomain for each customer customer.myapp.com. in my nginx i configured wildcard ssl certificate. (*.myapp.com) and it works.

how can I allow my customer to connect their own domain to their subdomain with ssl?

i.e customer.com => customer.myapp.com

I don't want to manually add certificate each customer. I want it to be automatically.

how could it have done with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

like with all things it depends on **your configuration**.

You sure are right, a wildcard certificate (*.myapp.com) can be used for **all subdomains**.

This means that for each customer you want to give a subdomain to, you can use the **same wildcard certificate**.

But as for how to implement it:

Show us how your configuration looks now, and we may help you automate it.